# Проверка формул на тождественность

Tags: алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ

Есть редактор формул для показателей, формула сохраняется в виде текстовой строки. Затем при вычислении показателя, формула разбирается в структуру в виде дерева и рассчитывается. Как проверить что введенная формула не была сохранена ранее для какого-то другого показателя? Например формула вида `(a+b)*c` равна `ac+bc`. Буду благодарен любой помощи, хотя бы ссылке на какую-нибудь литературу.

Comment: Ох. У вас просят написать систему символьной математики, наподобие Wolfram'а? Если это студенческий проект, это крутой проект, поздравляю. Если это задание на работе, требуйте позицию сениора и утроение зарплаты.

Comment: Это и есть задание по работе, и система почти готова, хочу прикрутить проверку на тождественность, потому и написал что буду рад любой ссылке на литературу.

Comment: Гуглите «системы символьной математики», и это задание _очень_ сложное, если подходить к нему серьёзно. Например, вам придётся знать, что формулы `sin(x)^2` и `1 - cos(x)^2` одинаковые.

Comment: @VladD, думаю, ему надо более примитивные формулы объединять.

Comment: @Qwertiy Не все формулы примитивные, у некоторых синтаксис как у mdx, агрегатная функция с обходом по какому-то из измерений

Comment: Мне кажется, пользователь, который ввёл `sin(x)^2`, не очень обрадуется, увидев сообщение _"Формула `1 - cos(x)^2` уже существует"_ ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy: А чем отличается упрощение `1 - cos^2 x` до `sin^2 x` от `ac + bc` до `(a + b)c`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: А сообщение можно поменять на «эквивалентная формула `1 - cos(x)^2` уже существует»

Comment: я знаю только один надежный способ решить эту задачу, не заходя в символьные вычисления - вычислить значение обеих функций на всей области определения и сравнить. В компиляторах есть подобная задача (упрощать выражения, раскрывать скобки) и там её ещё не до конца решили.

Comment: @KoVadim это было первым что пришло мне в голову, взять и подставить в качестве аргументов функций простые числа из разных разрядов и посчитать выражения, но как тогда быть с формулами вида А1+Мах(Сумма(B1,"Год")) ? Где "год" это измерение и оно может изменится и аналогичная формула с другим измерением будет принята за тождественное. Или я вас не правильно понял?

Comment: думаю, это очевидно, что функции должны получить на вход одинаковые наборы данных. Кстати, это первый этап - получить список всех переменных, от которых зависит формула. Если они одинаковые или один набор включает другой - повод задуматься.

Comment: @AlekseiChibisov Если Вы умеете делать символьные вычисления, то вычтите одну формулу из другой. Получили 0 - тождественны. Получили константу - думайте

Comment: @Anton Shchyrov вычесть из одного дерева другое?Каким образом это делается?

Comment: @KoVadim А как можно проверить на всей области видимости? 1. У вас по сути бесконечность в одну и другую сторону. Как вы выберете начало и конец? 2. С каким шагом сверять? 0.01, 0,001 и т.д.? По какому критерию его выбирать?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что со 100%-ными гарантиями задачу не решить.
По-моему, следует поступить так.
1. Научиться описывать область определения параметров функции по принципу "общее-особенное", где под "общим" понимается тип переменной и его границы, а под "особенным" - исключения (зоны особого внимания).
2. Научиться описывать область определения функции нескольких параметров (решающее правило "попали-не попали").
3. Написать генератор для каждого параметра и проверку для области определения.
4. Написать тесты для перекрёстной сверки функций, отдельно - по параметрам и областям определения.
5. Написать тест сверки значений функций.
6. Прочитать дополнительную литературу по юнит-тестам.
7. Научиться составлять понятные отчёты по результатам проверки (колеблющийся потребитель должен за деревьями увидеть лес).